# d3.js Projection for Washington DC area

Tags: coordinate-system, d3

I'm making a small thematic map of the Washington DC area using d3.js.

Everything I've tried "tilts" the square of DC.

Is there a d3 projection that will put DC at the right angle?

https://github.com/d3/d3-geo-projection/

Comment: Try Mercator, or if you can figure it out, try moving the central meridian or longitude of origin/center to DC. On a very quick look, I couldn't figure out how to do that. Hmmm, it might be via a .rotate(rotation in degrees), see http://www.d3noob.org/2013/03/a-simple-d3js-map-explained.html

Comment: DC itself uses Maryland State Plane (26985) for map products; I'd recommend matching what folks are used to seeing, even if there is a bit of tilt.

Comment: @Vince As far as I know, d3 only has spherical projection implementations so UTM and State Plane are not possible.

Comment: Hmmm. That's a bit like saying, "You can have any flavor of ice cream you want, as long as it's pistachio-apricot."

Comment: Can you provide your DC boundary data and perhaps give an example of what you have tried so far?

Comment: Here is what I have so far: http://smckissock.github.io/FairfaxFLAGS/page/districtmap/index.html

Answer (score 2):

D.C. is often projected with [Maryland State Plane](http://spatialreference.org/ref/esri/102285/), which is a conical projection. You can use `geoConicConformal` from [`d3-geo`](https://github.com/d3/d3-geo/) to create it in d3 (version 4):

```
const projection = d3.geoConicConformal()
    .rotate([77, 0])
    .center([0, 37.66])
    .parallels([38.3, 39.45])
```

If you want to learn more about crafting projections in d3.js, I highly recommend [this answer from Andrew Reid](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42267008/868724) on StackOverflow.